# Redirect to post with nancyfx

Tags: c#, nancy

With nancyfx is it possible to redirect to another method with post data?

In my example, after a user registers I want to automatically perform a login (I know there are other ways to achive this, I could extract the code from Post["/login"] and call it from both methods but this is a general question and I want to know if this is possible (Maybe I want to redirect to another module which is maintained by another developer and I can't just extract the code).

this is what I want to do (pseudo code)

```
return RedirectToModule<LoginModule>()
           .WithFormsValue("username", model.UserName)
           .WithFormsValue("password", model.Password);
```

and here is an example with two modules.

```
public class LoginModule : NancyModule
{
    public LoginModule()
    {
        Get["/login"] = _ => {
            return View["login"]; // return login view
        }
        Post["/login"] = _=> {
            // 1. get model
            var model = this.Bind<LoginViewModel>();
            // 2. perform login
            // ...
            // 3. redirect to home
            return Response.AsRedirect("~/");            
        };
    }
}    
public class RegisterModule : NancyModule
{
    public RegisterModule()
    {
        Get["/register"] = _=> {
            return View["register"]; // return register view
        };
        Post["/register"] = _ => {

              // 1. get model
              var model = this.Bind<RegisterModel>();
              // 2. create new User
              // ...
              // 3. redirect To /login with post data (pseudocode)
              return RedirectToModule<LoginModule>()
                 .WithFormsValue("username", model.UserName)
                 .WithFormsValue("password", model.Password);
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: I had explored something similar for a project I was doing and came to the conclusion that it was easily accomplished. You can get the IOC container and create an instance of `LoginModule` then directly call the `Post["/Login"]` method, but the parameters are not clear. The method I settled on was creating a third class that could be instantiated from either module that contained the common methods.

Comment: @RonBeyer I'd argue that what you're doing is the correct way and not calling a HTTP POST to another module. Doing a HTTP POST within a module that has access to the codebase is an overkill and using an IoC container makes much more sense. Regarding the original question, if you absolutely must, you can use the `HttpClient` and `PostAsync()` (not NancyFX specific) but I'm not sure if you can directly do it within Nancy itself.

Comment: @kha Yes, I do believe it would be the more "correct" way, even if it was a little more difficult to implement (having to break things out). This resulted in my having to create an `ILoginManager` interface and a concrete implementation, then its a little easier since you don't need to specifically use the IoC container, you just add `ILoginManager` to the constructor arguments and let the IoC take care of injecting it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. `HttpClient` would not work since the server itself would be the client but getting the Module from the IOC container and calling the method myself could be a quick and dirty solution (I tink I have to figure out myself how to modify the parameter to fit my needs).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that with a `307 temporary redirect`, but to do that you have to setup the redirect response "by hand":

```
public class RegisterModule : NancyModule
{
    public RegisterModule()
    {
        Get["/register"] = _=> {
          return View["register"]; // return register view
        };
        Post["/register"] = _ => {
          // 1. get model
          var model = this.Bind<RegisterModel>();
          // 2. create new User
          // ...
          // 3. redirect To /login with post data (pseudocode)
          return 
              Negotiate
              .WithStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.TemporaryRedirect)
              .WithHeader("Location", "/login");
      };
   }
}
```

This tells the client to resubmit the request to the URL indicated in the `Location` header with the same HTTP method and with the same body (including the form values).

If you want you could create an extension on `Negotiator` to make this response in one go:

```
public Negotiator WithTemporaryRedirect(this Negotiator self, string location) =>
      self.Negotiate
          .WithStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.TemporaryRedirect)
          .WithHeader("Location", "/login");
```

Comment: But that would redirect to my `Get["/login"]` or am I missing something?

Comment: 307 instructs the client use the same HTTP method as was used originally. That is the client does a `POST` and gets a 307 response it _should_ do a `POST` to the URL in the `Location` response header.